# Where is ansible's group_var/ folder located?

Tags: ansible

Hey guy's working my way through Ansibles guide but I can't find where group_var is located on the system, or where it should be nested if I need to create it.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, it's created at the top level of your playbook directory. According to [Ansible best practices](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_best_practices.html#directory-layout), create the directory at the same level as your playbooks and roles directory.

Comment: Hey Brian thanks for getting back to me, on an ubuntu box where would it store all of these? I'm not finding the directory

Comment: You can store them anywhere you'd like. Group vars are generally specific to your project, so, using the example in the the link I posted, you just create a directory for your project and create the folders within.

Answer (score 1):

`group_vars` can be located parallel to your playbook AND parallel to your inventory. This can, but is not required to be the same.